# Bell state Orthogonality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-entanglement

Given the Bell states $|\Psi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|H\rangle_1|V\rangle_2-|V\rangle_1|H\rangle_2)$ and $|\Phi^-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|H\rangle_1|H\rangle_2-|V\rangle_1|V\rangle_2)$, I want to show that these are orthogonal, but I am having trouble with seeing how they are. When I look at the inner product I get

$$\langle\Phi^-|\Psi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(\langle H_1\langle H_2|H_1\rangle V_2\rangle + \langle H_1 \langle H_2|V_1\rangle H_2\rangle - \langle V_1 \langle V_2|H_1\rangle V_2\rangle - \langle V_1\langle V_2|V_1\rangle H_2\rangle)$$

I know that this must equal zero to prove that they are orthogonal, but I am not seeing how this is the case. (In this case, H is for horizontal polarization and V for vertical).

Comment: Hint: $(\langle A|_1\langle B|_2)(|C\rangle _1|D\rangle_2)=\langle A|C \rangle_1 \langle B|D \rangle_2$ by the definition of a tensor product space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me rewrite $A=|H\rangle_1$, $B=|V\rangle_1$, $X=|H\rangle_2$, $Y=|V\rangle_2$ for typographical clarity.

Then $A$ is (by assumption) orthogonal to $B$, so $A\otimes X$ is orthogonal to $B\otimes X$, and $A\otimes Y$ is orthogonal to $B\otimes Y$.

Also $X$ is (by assumption) orthogonal to $Y$, so $A\otimes X$ is orthogonal to $A\otimes Y$, and $B\otimes X$ is orthogonal to $B\otimes Y$.

So the inner product $(A\otimes Y-B\otimes X,A\otimes X - B\otimes Y)$ can be expanded into four terms, each of which we've already agreed is zero.

That's the proof you want.  As to where you went wrong, I already can't make sense of your notation $\langle H_1\langle H_2|H_1\rangle V_2\rangle$, or even the interior part $\langle H_2|H_1\rangle$.  $H_1$ and $H_2$ (which I've called $A$ and $X$) belong to two completely different vector spaces that have nothing to do with each other.  How can it make sense to talk about their inner product?